# Seeking alternative to storing binaries in git for devops

Tags: deployment, best-practices

I'm not sure how to ask this best practices question since I know many StackExchange users evidently think best practices are a bad thing ...

We've got Salt and Vagrant configured to stand up servers with a variety of open source software.  Some of the libraries are obscure and not hosted on maven repos so we wish to host the libraries ourselves, these are typically large gz files totaling less than 1 GB.  We don't want to put them in git so we're looking for advice on how others do this.  We tried Dropbox but it doesn't appear to work well for this.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not set up your own maven repo?

Comment: It takes about 5 minutes according to them: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

I went with AWS S3 hosting which seems to have the simplicity we need.